# Show that the even coefficients (n even) of the Fourier sin series of f(x) on $0 \le x \le L$ are zero.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider a function that is even around $x= \frac{L}{2}$

Is this correct or should I add more?

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$

But $sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ around $\frac{L}{2}$ is odd for all n even implies $f(x)sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ is odd around $\frac{L}{2}$ for n even implies $b_n =0$ for n even

Comment: It makes sense. Do you need to substantiate any of your claims? As in, do you need to show that $sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ is odd about $\frac{L}{2}$ for $n$ even?

Comment: Yes, can you refresh my memory and explain how please?

Comment: This ought to work... Don't know if there's a more elegant way. I claim $f(-x+a)=-f(x+a)$ implies odd about $a$... Essentially, if you translate the function to the origin and show its odd there, then its odd at the point $a$ of interest.

You can show $sin(-\frac{n\pi x}{L}+\frac{n\pi}{2}) = -sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}+\frac{n\pi}{2})$ for even n.